# react native create custom template

Tags: react-native

Tried following this tutorial [Eliminate Boilerplate with React Native Templates](https://donniewest.com/eliminate-boilerplate-with-react-native-templates/) but it kept [failing for me](https://github.com/CodeKoalas/react-native-template-koality/issues/5#issuecomment-337731089)

I would like to make an template with some default code like this

```
...
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{fontFamily: 'SomeAwesomeFont'}>
        <Text>Hello </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
...
```

and this in the package.json

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
},
```

and add some font files into `assets/fonts`

Was hoping to be able to do this this:

`▶ react-native init World --template HelloTemplate`

`▶ cd World`

`▶ react-native link`

---

## Update

@ChrisGierman pointed me to the answer (thank you). The entire folder must be named `react-native-template-HelloTemplate`.

Comment: does my answer work for you? I've also written a blog post, which I will publish soon to answer this more comprehensively

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much for your answer. I think that this is what I did before I posted an question on SO, but I'll give your answer a try tomorrow and mark you answer if it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

--== **UPDATE** ==--

I wrote a blog post that pretty much reiterates what I've written below, but I think it's a bit more clear and comprehensive.

https://medium.com/@chris.geirman/the-1-2-3s-of-react-native-templates-1f5dda037e11

---

I've seen that article and have been meaning to give it a try for some time, so I thought I'd take this opportunity to do that and also help you out at the same time

You left out many details in your description, and because I cannot confirm whether you did them in the same way as the article or not, I thought they'd be worth reiterating the key points. Plus, I thought the article might be a bit vague. So here's what worked for me.

> Note: If you're sure you've done everything correct, then you may be able to skip to section 4 - publish. Your main problem might just be how you've run your cli command.

## 1) create `dependencies.json`

You mentioned a tiny part of what your `package.json` looks like, but the article specifies that your dependencies should go into a new file named `dependencies.json`. If your dependencies were these, then that file would look like this (note: my template is only dependent on `react-navigation`)...

```
{
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.15"
}
```

## 2) clean up your `package.json

The article next describes that you should remove dependencies, devDependencies, scripts and everything else unnecessary from the `package.json`. Template names must follow this convention...

```
react-native-template-{templateName}
```

My template is called `geirman` so this is what my final `package.json` looks like with all superfluous items removed. Again, this is the file in it's entirety.

```
{
  "name": "react-native-template-geirman",
  "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

## 3) delete native directories

```
rm -rf ./android
rm -rf ./ios
```

## 4) publish

Next, you're told to publish but it doesn't say how or where. You'd need to [publish to the npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages) following the naming convention above. Then you'd use the template with the following command...

```
react-native init myapp --template geirman
```

> Note: I  published my example to the npm registry, so the above will work.

But it seems you're actually trying to install it from the local file system. In that case, you'd need to provide the fully qualified path to the template like so...

```
react-native init myapp --template file:///Users/ChrisGeirman/dev/mobile/playground/templates/react-native-template-geirman
```

## other references

- if you want to see what a published template looks like, check out [`react-native-template-mobx`](https://github.com/80percent/react-native-template-mobx). It doesn't work anymore since it uses the `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` instead of the newer `index.js` entry point, but the same basic structure applies.
- [publish to the npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/publishing-npm-packages)

Comment: Think my problem is the "fully qualified path". In your example you create `gierman` but in your path you only use `react-native-template-geirman` without navigating into a `geriman` folder..? I tried several variations (see updated question) but without luck..

Comment: Found the issue. I have to use `react-native-template-` as the name of the folder.

Comment: Great to here it!